# Adding values from one file into a list in another file

Tags: yq

Using [Mike Farah's YQ](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/), I'm trying to merge certain values from stdin into a list in a file.

The command I'm currently using is:

```
yq ea -i '(select(fi==0).masterZones) += [(select(fi==1).AvailabilityZones[].ZoneName)]' test.txt -
```

For brevity, masterZones doesn't exist in test.txt. A truncated version of what comes into stdin is:

```
AvailabilityZones:
- GroupName: us-east-1
  ZoneName: us-east-1a
- GroupName: us-east-1
  ZoneName: us-east-1b
- GroupName: us-east-1
  ZoneName: us-east-1c
```

My output looks something like:

```
a: foo
b: bar
masterZones:
  - us-east-1a
  - us-east-1b
  - us-east-1c
---
AvailabilityZones:
- GroupName: us-east-1
  ZoneName: us-east-1a
- GroupName: us-east-1
  ZoneName: us-east-1b
- GroupName: us-east-1
  ZoneName: us-east-1c
```

I'd like to understand how to add just the list and also why it's appending stdin into the file instead of just my select clause. I get the feeling that what I want to do will require some ireduce magic that's a tad above my head but maybe I'm just missing something in eval-all that is appending the entire stdin into my file?

Comment: Do you want to unique the results (final)? Per the input above, your final `masterZones` will have repeated entries of `- us-east-1a
  - us-east-1b
  - us-east-1c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intention is to newly create `masterZones` on the `test.txt` or completely overwrite the values present in it, you could do

```
yq ea '
( 
  ( 
    select(fi==0).AvailabilityZones[].ZoneName ) as $item ireduce([]; . + $item
  ) 
) as $ma 
| select(fi == 1) | .masterZones += $ma ' - test.txt
```

The idea is to store the zone name values coming from standard input into an array (whole operation with `ireduce`) and on the test file, create a new path `masterZones` to update the array values.

Comment: Ah yea that works. I flipped test.txt and stdin because my shell didn't like stdin being first but I figured it had to involve ireduce somehow. Thanks again Inian! Also to answer your comment to my initial question, I didn't have a masterZones section in my initial test.txt file, only a: foo and b: bar.